# Crear componentes en vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs, component

Recien comienzo con vue entonces quizas mi duda tenga una respuesta evidente, cuestion que intento **crear un componente Vue, al hacer click en un boton.**
Mas precisamente que cuando yo haga click en un td de una tabla, llame a una funcion la cual me añadirá un componente que es una fila de dicha tabla.
No se si se puede siquiera, de ser asi, agradeciera que me orienten con otra solucion.

Yo intento algo como esto dentro del td encargado de añadir las filas:

```
<td colspan="5" @click="newAsiento()">New</td>
```

La funcion `newAsiento`:

```
newAsiento () {
   let tr = '<asiento-row :rowId="' + this.setId() + '"></asiento-row>';
   let tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');
   tbody.innerHTML = tbody.innerHTML + tr;
}
```

  Aclaraciones
- La funcion newAsiento es un metodo del componente padre
- A la etiqueta tbody le asigné el id 'tbody'
- La funcion setId nomas devuelve un valor numerico para diferenciar las filas con un numero unico
- El componente asiento-row es un 'tr' en pocas palabras

Yo esperaba tener un componente vue completamente funcional, pero me imprimió añadió el html que le indique en la variable tr dentro de la funcion `newAsiento`

Gracias. Diego.

Comment: Deberías revisar la documentación primero https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: Como ya te comentaron la documentación debe ser tu punto de partida, trata algo y cuando tengas dudas claras bienvenidas sean aquí en la comunidad

Comment: Lo hice pero no encuentro una respuesta a mi problema.

Comment: Entonces agrega lo que lleves, que resultado esperas y el resultado que obtienes al momento y así será mas fácil ayudarte, checa [ask]

Comment: Tienes razón me explique de una forma muy confusa, espero que me puedas entender ahora.

Answer (score 0):

Cómo estás usando vue? Es decir puedes poner el código completo? Es un componente que carga otro componente?

Si quieres que un componente padre reciba una acción del componente hijo (en este caso el td) debes crear un emit en el componente hijo (por eso es importante ver el documento más a detalle) en el caso contrario tu función

```
newAsiento () {
     ...
}
```

Debe de estar dentro de un method y al invocarlo quítale los paréntesis debe quedar así:

```
 @click="newAsiento">New
```

Sobran los paréntesis